# How to deal with line height adding padding at bottom of divs

Tags: padding, css

I have a site where I have `<div>`s that expand to contain images and a title. What I have done so far is create a hierarchy like this:

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="image_url"/>
    <div id="title">title</div>
</div>
```

then positioned the title like this:

```
#title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

but the title `<div>` sits below the bottom line of the image. I tried to reduce the `line-height` in the div and that fixed the problem of the text hanging over the image but messed up the text padding. Does anybody know how I should be doing things differently to position the title at the bottom right of the image in the 'correct' way?

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/BUpmr/3

Answer (score 1):

Images are inline by default, and that means they allow space for character descenders.

http://jsfiddle.net/BUpmr/10/

```
img {display: block}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many pixels you want to move it up from the bottom, you can just do it like this:

```
#title
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BUpmr/12/

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the space at the bottom isn't line height, it's the browser trying to align the bottom of the image with the baseline of the text.

To fix it, set `vertical-align: top` on the image: http://jsfiddle.net/VRyCF/2

Answer (score 0):

You're using position: absolute and that takes elements out of the document flow. In this case you want the image and the text element both to take up space, so use `position: relative` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/BUpmr/13/

1. Remove the `position: absolute;` from the body in the css
2. In #title change `position: absolute` to `position: relative;`
3. Add `width:600px` to the elements (because the image is 600px wide) (or make the width on `#title` smaller (say 550px) to put the text slightly more to the left.
4. add `text-align: right` to `#title` to get the text to in the right corner
5. add .thumb img {display:block;}

CSS:

```
    body {
        background-color: #eef;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #title{
        position: relative;
        text-align:right;
        width:550px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #0f0;
        padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    }

    .thumb{
        background-color: #f00;
            width:600px;
    }

   .thumb img {display:block;}
```